# Stuck on how to use .first and .last in a Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I need to create a method named first_and_last.  Take one argument - an array - and return a new array with only the first and last objects.

My attempt:

```
def first_and_last(a)
  first_and_last = [1,2,3]
  first_and_last.last.first
end
```

Here's where I get confused, it also says I need strings "a" and "d" along with the numbers.  However, there are 3 numbers and 4 strings.  I figured 0 would be the `.first` of the numbers.

```
describe "first_and_last" do
      it "creates new array with numbers" do
        expect( first_and_last([1,2,3]) ).to eq([1,3])
      end
      it "creates new array with strings" do
        expect( first_and_last(["a", "b", "c", "d"]) ).to eq(["a", "d"])
      end
    end
```

I'm not getting how to include both `1,2,3` and strings `"a", "b", "c", "d"` into the array while using the `.first` and `.last`

Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa The question is implied, but clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def first_and_last(array)
  [array.first, array.last]
end
```

Comment: Good, workmanlike answer. "Beautiful?" Only to those infatuated with Ruby. But that's fine.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: `first_and_last(array).first` and `first_and_last(array).second` :D

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not clear. You can implement it like this.

```
def first_and_last(a)
  a.values_at(0, -1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the correct answer from Mori, lets break down why your code is not working

Your method takes one parameter but you manually assign the `first_and_last` variable.

When you call `.last` on an array it will give you the last element, thus this part of your code is somewhat correct `first_and_last.last`. But when you add `.first` onto the variable you are actually calling `.first` on a FixNum because the last element of the array was a number. Check out codeacademy for more lessons on arrays

EDIT:

```
   #ATTN ONE LINER AHEAD
   #Credit to Mori..
   def first_and_last(a); [a.first,a.last]; end
```

Comment: Yeah I'm actually learning through a boot camp and the code they gave me was:
`def first_and_last(a)

end`

So I'm fairly confused as to why they would give me one argument `a` and say give the `.first` and `.last`

Comment: Check my edit. They may have wanted something concise like so. Functionality wise they want to know, if given an array as a parameter can you provide the first and last elements.

Comment: I was confused for a while and you made that a lot easier.  Thank you for your time!